# How do i retrieve distinct rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table in my database called `message` where users can send and retrieve messages.

Here is the layout:

**msg_id** **sender_id** **receiver_id** **date** **txt**

I want to be able to retrieve messages sent to a particular user, with only the last message for each user e.g. There might be more than one Message from user id `1`, but I only want to display the last message.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b57/3

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN messages m1
ON m.sender_id = m1.sender_id
  AND m.date<m1.date
WHERE m1.msg_id IS NULL
ORDER BY sender_id
```

OR

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN messages m1
ON m.receiver_id = m1.receiver_id
  AND m.date<m1.date
WHERE m1.msg_id IS NULL
ORDER BY receiver_id;
```

**UPDATE** Here is variant with flexible limit (2-3-4 ...any) of records per user. But keep in mind it could become very slow if you have millions of records.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b57/13

```
SELECT m.*
FROM
(SELECT *, 
   IF(@user=receiver_id,@user_index:=@user_index+1,@user_index:=1) idx,
   @user:=receiver_id
FROM messages 
ORDER BY receiver_id, `date` DESC
) m
WHERE m.idx<=2
```

**UPDATE 2* One another approach. I guess it could be faster:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bfbd/1

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT receiver_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(msg_id ORDER BY `date` DESC) ord
  FROM messages 
  GROUP BY receiver_id

) o
ON o.receiver_id = m.receiver_id
  and FIND_IN_SET(m.msg_id, o.ord) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
ORDER BY m.receiver_id, m.date DESC
  ;
```

Comment: How about trying more than one message from each user to know what i mean.

Comment: that is completely another way to do... This one I have in my answer is pretty fast. If you want to create universal request for all users limited by some variable 2-3-4-5 we need to create subquery which will break the performance. if you need one I can try.

Comment: Okay just please try! This has been giving me problem for long

Comment: That's nice but it's pretty slow.. Thanks anyway. i believe that will sustain me for the main time till got the real query for that.

Comment: try to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3348898/4421474  which is another solution, could be faster than mine

Comment: I  have many query that contain `GROUP BY` to do that work, but it's not ordering according to the last sent date. Something like the `GROUP BY` statement override the `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: Do you have `receiver_id` and `sender_id` indexed by the way?

Comment: Show me your `CREATE TABLE` statement, which columns are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You need use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for your query

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE receiver_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. The `QUERY` display more than 1 message but will not retrieve duplicate sender, only one by a sender.