# MYSQL limit the JOIN rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

I'v got 4 tables involve in the query:

the main table `items` holds items list
`suppliers` that holds the item supplier INNER JOIN by id
`item_categories` that holds the item category INNER JOIN by id

and `orders` table that hold orders in the follow struct:
`id`
.
.
.
`items` => a JSON that hold the items array in the order

example of items JSON:

```
{
"10": {
    "name": "item 1",
    "step": "1",
    "price": "140",
    "amount": "4"
},
"24": {
    "name": "item 2",
    "step": "1",
    "price": "6.2",
    "amount": "1"
},
"35": {
    "name": "item 3",
    "step": "1",
    "price": "2.9",
    "amount": "3"
},
"37": {
    "name": "item 4",
    "step": "1",
    "price": "3.9",
    "amount": "2"
}}
```

i want to get table of all the item with the last 4 orders amount

I mange the make this query:

```
SELECT 
`items`.`id`, 
`items`.`part_number`, 
`item_categories`.`name`    AS category, 
`suppliers`.`name`          AS supplier, 
`items`.`supplier_id`, 
`items`.`name`, 
`items`.`inventory`, 
`items`.`package_items`, 
`items`.`order_step`, 
`items`.`price`, 
`items`.`discount`, 
`items`.`scale`, 
`items`.`by_scale`, 
`items`.`has_tax`, 
`items`.`category_id`, 
`items`.`enable`, 
Group_concat(Json_extract(`orders`.`items`, Concat('$."', `items`.`id`, '".amount')) ORDER BY 
`orders`.`createdate` DESC) AS last_orders_amount 
FROM   `items` 
       INNER JOIN `suppliers` 
               ON `items`.`supplier_id` = `suppliers`.`id` 
       INNER JOIN `item_categories` 
               ON `items`.`category_id` = `item_categories`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `orders` 
              ON 
Json_extract(`orders`.`items`, Concat('$."', `items`.`id`, '"')) IS 
NOT NULL 
WHERE  1 
GROUP  BY `items`.`id`
```

which give me all the items with all the last orders

so my final question is , is there a way that i could LIMIT the results i get by the LEFT JOIN ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, but probably not ideal would be to:

```
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `orders` LIMIT 1000) ordrs 
              ON 
Json_extract(`ordrs`.`items`, Concat('$."', `items`.`id`, '"')) IS 
NOT NULL 
WHERE  1 
GROUP  BY `items`.`id`
```

So basically just nest a select statement as your join table. Will edit if I think of a better way.

EDIT:

If you have access to rank, it looks like that will also work. Source:

[How to limit results of a LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348705/how-to-limit-results-of-a-left-join)

If rank is available to you that is probably the better option

Comment: If you do it with the nested select you also may need to be specific about which columns you are selecting from orders instead of '*'

Comment: how can i get the `items`.`id`  into the   nested select  ??