# MYSQL use outer select value in inner select

Tags: php, mysql, join

I know that this question asked frequently but i didn't find any answer (or that its not possible):

I'v got this query

```
SELECT
  `items`.`id`,
  `items`.`part_number`,
  `item_categories`.`name` AS category,
  `suppliers`.`name` AS supplier,
  `items`.`supplier_id`,
  `items`.`name`,
  `items`.`inventory`,
  `items`.`package_items`,
  `items`.`order_step`,
  `items`.`price`,
  `items`.`discount`,
  `items`.`scale`,
  `items`.`by_scale`,
  `items`.`has_tax`,
  `items`.`category_id`,
  `items`.`enable`,
  orders.last_orders_amount
FROM
  `items`
INNER JOIN
  `suppliers` ON `items`.`supplier_id` = `suppliers`.`id`
INNER JOIN
  `item_categories` ON `items`.`category_id` = `item_categories`.`id`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      `orders`.`items`,
      CONCAT('$."',
      "3",
      '".amount')
    )
  ORDER BY
    `orders`.`createDate` DESC
  ) AS last_orders_amount
FROM
  `orders`
WHERE
  JSON_EXTRACT(`orders`.`items`,
  '$."3"') IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 4
) orders ON orders.last_orders_amount IS NOT NULL
WHERE
  1
```

basically i want to get all the 'items' with there last 4 occurrences in 'orders' base on `item`.`id`.

I need to replace the number **3** in that query to `item`.`id` from the outer join

(i know that there is INNER JOIN cause to get only items that have occurrences in orders)

Comment: "MYSQL use outer select value in inner select" sounds to me you want to use a corelated subquery.. but your question is hard to understand without example data, expected result and i don't feel like to reverse engineer your SQL

Comment: its follow up to this post : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103021/mysql-limit-the-join-rows